# How can I bind a draconic spirit?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, summoning, dragons, duration

My wizard is fond of [summoning](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-elemental) or [conjuring](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/conjure-elemental) elementals and binding them using *[planar binding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding)*, keeping them around for a while.  Even keeping them a day is awesome, because concentration is not required, although longer is better, at a 1000 a pop.

Whether the combination of [summoning/conjuring and binding](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147793/is-there-enough-time-to-planar-bind-a-creature-conjured-by-a-1-hour-duration-spe) works isn't the question; the GM has ruled that it does.  Likewise, the issue of [concentration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/140755/does-planar-binding-require-you-to-keep-concentrating-on-the-summoning-spell?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C90.8793) isn't the question; the GM has ruled in that regard also.  (Hours of work on my part, they flip through a few items, and say "sure".)

The issue is . . . elementals are not enough.  I need power, more power.  Elementals are great, but they tend to have low saving throws, and it sucks having your elemental incapacitated or turned against you.

I want . . . a dragon.

Maybe an actual dragon might be a bit overkill, hopefully not literally.  A draconic spirit would be great.

Specifically, I want to [summon a draconic spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-draconic-spirit) and bind it, in a similar manner as planar binding, but planar binding won't work because it doesn't work on dragons.  I've searched through the 5e compendium and not run across anything that really fits, but it's a big game and I'm hoping someone has an angle I haven't thought of.

I intend to research in-game, but our GM prefers if we bring solutions and information rather than coming at it empty-handed.  The wizard is 14th level, with 15th looming over the horizon.  If there's something that will work that is out of the wizard's reach, that's okay.  I could conceivably beg, borrow, barter, or buy whatever it is.  If there's any way at all, that opens the door.  Okay, not any way at all, a way short of wish.  That's a price too high.

For what it's worth, my wizard has already tried it -- the draconic spirit was happy enough to hang around for an hour, but planar binding did nothing (GM: does that work on dragons? Wizard: maybe? GM, looking at spell, "nope".)

In fact, I really am less interested in *binding* it than getting it to hang around more-or-less voluntarily, so if actual coercion weren't necessary that would be a bonus.

**So, my question is this:  how can I extend the stay of a summoned draconic spirit in a way similar to planar binding, recognizing that planar binding won't work on dragons?**

Comment: I'm somewhat confused, what does binding it accomplish when it already treats you as an ally and obeys your verbal commands? Are you just trying to make the spell's duration longer than 1 hour? Also, what level is your Wizard? This will impact what options are available. Or perhaps answers should just assume *anything* is an option and leave working it out to you and your table? Any details specific to the table would help answerers to better gauge what's available and what exactly you're aiming to do

Comment: This will largely depend on if your DM treats Summoning and Conjuring as different things... But conjuring something then using binding on it is within one of the ideas for the spell as evidenced in the description of Planar Binding by summoning it into a circle first. @Exempt-Medic

Comment: @Exempt-Medic The issue is that planar binding binds "a celestial, an elemental, a fey, or a fiend".  A draconic spirit is a dragon.  And yes, this is specifically so that the ally stays around for longer than an hour, and doesn't require concentration.  A draconic spirit that hangs around an hour and takes concentration - awesome;  one that hangs around longer, no concentration, priceless!  (At least certainly worth a 1000!)

Comment: What level is your wizard, i.e. which spells does he have access to?

Comment: Groody, 14th. Unless I'm missing something the wizard does not have something that specifically can bind a dragon the way planar binding can bind a celestial, fey, elemental, or fiend.  I said in the question, "If there's something that will work that is out of the wizard's reach, that's okay. I could conceivably beg, borrow, barter, or buy whatever it is."  If I've somehow missed something simple, that would be great to know, but I think the answer, if there is one, is going to be something obscure, and it will give me a clue to a solution I can suggest to the GM, not something I can just do.

Comment: I opened my copy of Fizbans to check this spell and see if I could help, but the only thought I came away with was ... why. The spells in this book are so poor :(
This isn't a question complaint, just a comment on the spell.

Answer (score 4):

### Try True Polymorph and Glyph shenanigans

The light is not worth the candle here, but this is a way that *might* get you there (and if not I hope smart people will point out why not). You will need an archmage to help. The timing may be a bit iffy, but I think it works. Follow this four step procedure:

1. Prepare an upcast [Glyph of Warding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/glyph-of-warding) with your Summon Draconic Spirit Spell. The glyph has been errataed to not only cause hostile effects so you can summon a friendly spirit. There is no need to rely on a Magic Circle (which would not work on a dragon). Glyph states *If the spell requires concentration, it lasts until the end of its full duration*, so your spirit should stick around for the full hour without needing your concentration enabling you to cast the Binding. Set the Glyph to trigger when you open your mouth to start casting the Planar Binding or such.
2. Have the friendly archmage cast [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) on the dragon, temporarily turning it into a Celestial, Elemental, Fiend, or Fey. It now is a valid target for Planar Binding. When they do so is dependent on how you rule [when the target for a spell is checked](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/114403/at-what-point-does-a-caster-define-the-target-of-a-spell). It seems that is unclear RAW, but likely at the end of the casting. So they have plenty of time, and can do that while you are halfway into casting the Binding. If it were checked at the beginning of casting, it might work if they Polymorph as a reaction to the dragon being summoned.
3. Cast your [Planar Binding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding) as you usually would on a summoned creature. It says *If the creature was summoned or created by another spell, that spell's duration is extended to match the duration of this spell*, so this should extend the summons if needed, too. At the end of the hour, you are binding the Fey formerly known as a Dragon. It is now bound for however long your Binding spell level indicates. (At least I see nothing in Planar Binding that says it would drop off if the creature is polymorphed into another creature type).
4. The archmage drops the Polymorph concentration. Your bound creature reverts back to being a Dragon. You pay the archmage their outrageous fee for their services and happily trundle off with your new Dragon pal in tow.

Comment: This is pretty sweet.  Getting access to True Poly for free only requires waiting.  One more example where I feel I have not even begun to exploit Glyph.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, if you wanted to do it without any help at all (and had attained level 17), you could upcast a second glyph that then releases the TP in step 2.

Comment: Yep.  This is almost sure-fire, I just need to wait til 17th.

Answer (score 3):

### Subdue, don't Summon

My other answer was a technical treatise on how what you ask could be achieved using the 5e rules mechanics. I do however think that this is approaching this from the wrong perspective. You say:

> I want . . . a dragon.

If that's really what you are after, let's be honest: a Draconic Spirit is a sorry excuse for an actual *dragon*. Even if you can get it to stick around.

This is an area where the original game was arguably cooler than 5e. In OD&D, there were actual *rules* on how to subdue a dragon, and make it follow you around. (Granted, they were broken in that it was apparently a lot easier to do that than to kill the dragon, when it should have been a lot more difficult as appropriate for the bonus of *getting your very own dragon*). In the original Greyhawk campaign, Rob Kuntz player character Robilar ended up with a pair of Green Dragons, a fact that impressed him enough to [name his blog](http://lordofthegreendragons.blogspot.com/) after the fact. Gary Gygax main player character [Mordenkainen had a pair of Red Dragons named Porky and Gorky](http://thecampaign20xx.blogspot.com/2019/10/dungeons-dragons-guide-to-mordenkainen.html).

Now, 5e does not have actual rules for subduing dragons, and in fact makes it unlikely to subdue chromatic dragons with general comments such as:

> They believe in their innate right to rule, and this belief is the cornerstone of every chromatic dragon's personality and worldview. Trying to humble a chromatic dragon is like trying to convince the wind to stop blowing. (MM, p. 86)

Also Fizban's entirely omits the subject. However, there is hope. The **White Dragon** specifically says:

> Powerful creatures can sometimes gain a white dragon's obedience through a demonstration of physical or magical might. (MM p. 102)

So, it might be possible to travel to the icy north, and subdue a Young White Dragon with appropriate demonstrations of magical prowess that your character as a level 14 Wizard should be able to produce. You'll get a real dragon, with a proper breath weapon that deals 10d8 instead of a measly 2d6. And you'll get a constant source of worry, of course, that the chaotic evil and rather stupid dragon will behave, and your DM will have a constant source of entertainment for all involved.

This clearly is something that you need to work out by collaborating on it with your DM. And you will have to undertake actual adventures to achieve it. It may or may not fit your group or DM's style, but if it does, I think this is the better solution.

Comment: Yeah, the white dragon is not happening.  I need a dragon that will behave.  But you bring up a good point.  Maybe I can just befriend one.  One benefit of a draconic spirit is that the GM has ruled that the "you call forth a ____ spirit" spells are not actually wrenching a creature from its existing life, but rather using magic to animate a spirit.  Binding a creature into servitude is clearly yet another blemish on my already somewhat tarnished soul.  It turns out that in the quest for ultimate arcane power the lure of the dark side is powerful, who knew.  I wonder how Gandolf did it.

Comment: Gandalf had an unfair advantage, being a Maja and all... We ended up befriending the Gold Dragon from Dragon Heist, and offering him to stay in our place in Trollskull Alley. About the best insurance you can think of. We regularily gift him with jewels to eat, so he keeps happy and sticks around. But of course, he's not tagging along on adventures

Comment: Oh, and tell me about the temptations of the dark side. I play a tree-hugging half-elf wizard, who spent their recent past animating the dead left and right and wearing a cursed but powerful Belt of Dwarvenkind in some sinister dungeon.

Answer (score 1):

### True Polymorph (Object to Creature) for real dragon friend

If it is a longer lasting dragon friend (without using concentration to keep it) that you want, then you only need **True Polymorph** and a **large object** that would be around the same size as a large creature.

1. Cast [True Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) on the large object and turn it into a CR 9 (or below) **young dragon** (you can create any creature that is **CR 9 or below** via the spell text).
2. While concentrating on the spell talk to it, feed it, don't fight things or boss it around, and offer it things it likes for that whole hour until it is your best buddy (True Polymorph states, for the object to creature method: "If the spell becomes permanent, you no longer control the creature. It might **remain friendly** to you, depending on **how you have treated it**").
3. The hour ends and the spell is permanent, and you now have your own young dragon best friend and possible mount that does not require concentration.
4. Also, this way if it gets dispelled, drops to 0 hp, or dies, it's just that large object again and you cast the spell on it again doing steps 1-3 to get your buddy back. True Polymorph, by itself, is essentially free as well if you use a spell focus or component pouch.

If you do make one, and you are a **good aligned** character, I highly suggest making a CR 9 [Young Silver Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/17075-young-silver-dragon), as they are described as "the **friendliest** and most social of the metallic dragons, **silver dragons cheerfully assist good creatures in need**." They also love hanging out with humanoids, but if you are an actual human they like them the most. Also, stuff they like is listed on the page in the link of their name above, along with their stats, etc. They basically like anything to do with history or interesting technologies. They are the nerdy dragons.

To address the [other solution](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/196238/83405) above that involves using [planar binding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/planar-binding) there is a fault to it that would make it **possibly** not work that way. Planar binding states: "or **created by** another spell, **that** spell's duration is extended to match the duration of this spell", and when you use True Polymorph you are creating a creature via spell, so the duration of the True Polymorph with the creature being a fey, fiend, elemental, or celestial would be extended, not the [Summon Draconic Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-draconic-spirit). **Although this depends on your DM** and how much of a stickler they are on wordings.

This [other solution](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/198549/83405) above could work, but it involves **more spell slots, more time, more money, and only lasts 180 days at most** while also being a bit risky lol. However, if you are a **neutral or evil aligned** character that often does bad things, then their option might be the only way to go.

Comment: True Polymorph does not create a creature when you use it on a creature, it merely *transforms* the creature. The spell that created it is still Summon Draconic Spirit, so I think the passage on that is technically wrong. If your main plan would work will depend very much on the DM; I know it wouldn't with me as DM or with our DM, because one hour is rather short to befriend a creature to permanent companionship, but I can see it work with a lenient one.  The section on silver dragons is great, so I’ll give you a +1. Welcome to StackExchange.

Comment: @Nobody the Hobgoblin
Yeah, I figured the True Polymorph creation bit could be wrong. That's why I wrote in "possibly" in bold lol.

For the hour to befriend it, I think it is possible to at least begin a permanent friendship in that time because the spell says "it might remain friendly to you", it was once an object and might want a friend now that it has consciousness (you are the first creature it has had positive relations with), and the fact that silver dragons are curious, friendly towards humanoids (enjoy companionship with them), and enjoy helping people. Always up to DMs of course.

Comment: I like the True Poly idea just the same.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### True Polymorph for getting a real dragon

After some due consideration, here is yet another approach that combines the benefits of the other two: a technical method and getting an actual dragon.

1. Prepare an upcast *Glyph of Warding* with a *Conjure Elemental* spell (cast at level 6, 7 or 8, using the next higher slot for the glyph), as in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/196169/how-can-i-bind-a-draconic-spirit/196238#196238). I know of Invisible Stalker as an option for CR 6, of Elemental Myrmidons for CR 7, and Big Xorn (from DotMM) for CR 8 -- maybe not all of them will be available, but the Invisible Stalker should be.
2. Prepare another upcast *Glyph of Warding* using your level 9 slot and store a level 8 *Planar Binding* in it, triggering on the appearance of the elemental, and binding it to servitude for 180 days.
3. Once the elemental is bound, cast *True Polymorph* on it, and hold the concentration until the effect is permanent. Depending on the challenge rating of the elemental you summoned, you will be able to turn it into either a Young White Dragon (CR 6), a Young Black Dragon (CR 7), or a Young Green Dragon (CR 8).

What about this dragon?

- The traits of vanishing and being forced to be friendly to you imposed by the *Conjure Elemental* spell are [not part of the creature's statistics](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/138783/what-all-is-included-in-a-creatures-game-statistics) that are replaced by *True Polymorph*, so they will endure for the duration of *Planar Binding* and serve you during this time
- The polymorphed creature "*retains its alignment and personality*", so it will hate you just as much as the original elemental, but like it not be able to do anything about it while under the effect of *Planar Binding*

This all will cost you at least two days, 2 level 9 slots, 1 level 8 slot, 1 level 7 slot and 1 level 6 slot, plus the material components. Not a cheap undertaking by any means.

You now have a dragon, which will serve you for 180 days, and then vanish.

---

*P.S. I expect from your comments that your DM might opt to shut this down, and there is enough ambiguity about the rules involved here to make this ruling territory even without invoking rule 0. The due diligence to obtain precendence on what is [likely RAW is here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198539/what-happens-when-true-polymorph-is-cast-on-a-conjured-creature), and I think this is as close to RAW as you can get.*